# How can I share claims among multiple web applications?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-identity

I'd like to delegate login/logout functionality to **one** web application instead of having this in all application. This is how I'd like to set it up:

1) User navigates to app "foo"

2) User is **not** logged in, so is redirected to app "authorization"

3) App "authorization" uses Azure AD as Identity provider (IDP) and redirects to a a microsoft login page.

4) The user enters username and password

5) User is redirected to "authorization"

6) User is redirected to app "foo" and is logged in

This works up till step 6. Here the claims set by the IDP are lost, which is sane since only app "authorization" is registered in the IDP.

But is there a way to accomplish this scenario? Cheers!

Comment: For me it's not clear what should happen here. Guessing you are using asp core identity with cookies, you claims should be stored in a cookie. Then your 'foo' app must receive and read those cookies. Do the requests contain those cookies? If yes 'foo' app must be able to decrypt the values that requires a shared key storage (see data protection in docs). Or is this the wrong direction?

Comment: Your assumptions are absolutely right. So I guess I can’t just forward the claims. I have to create new claims which can be read by foo.

Comment: Have you tried identityserver4?We use it for authentication.Our client app is token based.It works great.

Comment: I think it largely depends on your type of app. If we're talking about an SPA, IdentityServer is the option we use too. If it's MVC it should work to share the claims as long as you're on the same domain (using a path to separate the apps) or sub domains and share the keys using Redis or AzureKeyVault.

Comment: It seems to me that the app "authorization" is acting as an IDP or sorts. Why not consider "Foo" authenticate directly with AAD?

Comment: @KalyanKrishna Following the single responsibility principle I'd like to delegate all interaction with the external IDP to a single application.

Comment: Its in all probability an antipattern. Each app should be uniquely identified to the IdP, so it can identify it correctly to the end user, let admins apply policies, do customizations (like claims), execute user assignments, record audits and telemetry and more. From security perspective, a vulnerability in your main app exposes all the other apps. Also apps can no longer choose the best AuthN flow that suits their purpose. I can go on, but frankly speaking you'd end up with a lot more work for yourself and that too at a cost for sacrificing security..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MohammadNiazmand suggested, consider IdentityServer4.  In your flow above "authorization" is the IdentityServer 4 service (but the user really doesn't interact directly with it, it's all redirects). The advantage here is that you can still use external providers (AD) with IS4 -- but then once AD has authenticated the user and redirects back to IS4, you can then insert your own custom claims using the ProfileService extension point if needed (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html).  Then all of your web apps just need to be setup to use IS4 for identity and everything is centralized and a single set of claims will be available to all apps.  IS4 supports Asp.Net Core Identity out of box (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html).